# Change in Button text color not reflecting

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, object, uibutton

I am facing a weird issue. I am changing the text color of my button when it is highlighted but visually no change at all.

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0 green:150.0 blue:150.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

try:

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0/256.0 green:150.0/256.0 blue:150.0/256.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Color components are floats between 0.0 and 1.0 !

Comment: The Color components are floats between 0.0 and 1.0, but the index starts at 0: `float/255.0` It should be: `[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0/255.0 green:150.0/255.0 blue:150.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]`